# closed (H264 track 1 is not valid: sprop-parameter-sets is missing (96 packetization-mode=1)

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I used FFmpeg6.1 to stream RTSP, but I received the following errors on the server:

> closed (H264 track 1 is not valid: sprop-parameter-sets is missing (96 packetization-mode=1)，client:Error occurred when opening output Server returned 400 Bad Request.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavutil/time.h>

static void encode(AVCodecContext *enc_ctx, AVFrame *frame, AVPacket *pkt,
                   AVFormatContext *outFormatCtx) {
    int ret;

    /* send the frame to the encoder */
    if (frame)
        printf("Send frame %3"PRId64"\n", frame->pts);

    ret = avcodec_send_frame(enc_ctx, frame);
    if (ret < 0) {
        char errbuf[AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE];
        av_strerror(ret, errbuf, AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending a frame for encoding ,%s\n", errbuf);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (ret >= 0) {
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(enc_ctx, pkt);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
            return;
        else if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error during encoding\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Write packet %3"PRId64" (size=%5d)\n", pkt->pts, pkt->size);
        av_write_frame(outFormatCtx, pkt); // Write the packet to the RTMP stream
        av_packet_unref(pkt);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_DEBUG);
    const char *rtmp_url, *codec_name;
    const AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *codecContext = NULL;
    int i, ret, x, y;
    AVFormatContext *outFormatCtx;
    AVStream *st;
    AVFrame *frame;
    AVPacket *pkt;
    uint8_t endcode[] = {0, 0, 1, 0xb7};

    if (argc <= 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <rtmp url> <codec name>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    rtmp_url = argv[1];
    codec_name = argv[2];
    avformat_network_init();
    /* find the mpeg1video encoder */
//    codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name(codec_name);
//    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4);
//    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_VP9);
//    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO);
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
//    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_AV1);
//    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H265);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec '%s' not found\n", codec_name);
        exit(1);
    }
    codecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!codecContext) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video codec context\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* ... (rest of the setup code) ... */
/* put sample parameters */
    codecContext->bit_rate = 400000;
    /* resolution must be a multiple of two */
    codecContext->width = 352;
    codecContext->height = 288;
    /* frames per second */
    codecContext->time_base = (AVRational) {1, 25};
    codecContext->framerate = (AVRational) {25, 1};

    /* emit one intra frame every ten frames
     * check frame pict_type before passing frame
     * to encoder, if frame->pict_type is AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I
     * then gop_size is ignored and the output of encoder
     * will always be I frame irrespective to gop_size
     */
    codecContext->gop_size = 10;
    codecContext->max_b_frames = 1;
    codecContext->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;



    /* Open the RTSP output */
//    const AVOutputFormat *ofmt = av_guess_format("tcp", NULL, NULL);
    const AVOutputFormat *ofmt = av_guess_format("rtsp", rtmp_url, NULL);
//    const AVOutputFormat *ofmt = av_guess_format("flv", NULL, NULL);
//    const AVOutputFormat *ofmt = av_guess_format("rtmp", NULL, NULL);
//    const AVOutputFormat *ofmt = av_guess_format("mpegts", NULL, NULL);
//    const AVOutputFormat *ofmt = av_guess_format("mp4", NULL, NULL);
    if (!ofmt) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find output format\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Allocate the output context */

/*    outFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (!outFormatCtx) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate output context\n");
        exit(1);
    }*/

    // 打开输出  这个会导致outFormatCtx 中的stream 为空，并且产生这个问题[rtsp @ 00000204f6218b80] No streams to mux were specified
    if (avformat_alloc_output_context2(&outFormatCtx, ofmt, "rtsp", rtmp_url) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate output context\n");
        return 1;
    }


    outFormatCtx->oformat = ofmt;
    outFormatCtx->url = av_strdup(rtmp_url);

    /* Add a video stream */
    st = avformat_new_stream(outFormatCtx, codec);
    if (!st) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate stream\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    st->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    st->codecpar->codec_id = codec->id;
    st->codecpar->width = 352;
    st->codecpar->height = 288;
    st->codecpar->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
//    st->codecpar = c;
//    st->codecpar->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    // Set video stream parameters
//    st->codecpar->framerate = (AVRational) {25, 1};
//    st->id=outFormatCtx->nb_streams-1;
    /* Set the output URL */
    av_dict_set(&outFormatCtx->metadata, "url", rtmp_url, 0);


    pkt = av_packet_alloc();
    if (!pkt)
        exit(1);


    if (codec->id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
        av_opt_set(codecContext->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);

    AVDictionary *opt = NULL;
/*    av_dict_set(&opt, "rtsp_transport", "udp", 0);
    av_dict_set(&opt, "announce_port", "1935", 0);
    av_dict_set(&opt, "enable-protocol", "rtsp", 0);
    av_dict_set(&opt, "protocol_whitelist", "file,udp,tcp,rtp,rtsp", 0);
    av_dict_set(&opt, "enable-protocol", "rtp", 0);
    av_dict_set(&opt, "enable-protocol", "rtsp", 0);
    av_dict_set(&opt, "enable-protocol", "udp", 0);
    av_dict_set(&opt, "enable-muxer", "rtsp", 0);
    av_dict_set(&opt, "enable-muxer", "rtp", 0);*/
    av_dict_set(&opt, "rtsp_transport", "tcp", 0);
    av_dict_set(&opt, "stimeout", "2000000", 0);
    av_dict_set(&opt, "max_delay", "500000", 0);
    av_dict_set(&opt, "sprop-parameter-sets", "asdgasdfs", AV_DICT_APPEND);
    /* open it */
    ret = avcodec_open2(codecContext, codec, &opt);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        exit(1);
    }
/*    // 打开RTSP输出URL  微软AI给出的代码
    if (!(outFormatCtx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        int ret = avio_open(&outFormatCtx->pb, rtmp_url, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0) {
//            std::cerr << "Could not open output URL " << out_url << std::endl;
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open output URL  %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
            return -1;
        }
    }*/

    avcodec_parameters_to_context(codecContext, st->codecpar);

/*    AVDictionary *options = NULL;
    av_dict_set(&options, "rtsp_transport", "tcp", 0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "stimeout", "2000000", 0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "max_delay", "500000", 0);
    // 初始化输出
    av_dict_set(&options, "rtsp_transport", "tcp", 0);
//设置 接收包间隔最大延迟，微秒
    av_dict_set(&options, "max_delay", "200000", 0);
// rtmp、rtsp延迟控制到最小
    av_dict_set(&options, "fflags", "nobuffer", 0);
// 在进行网络操作时允许的最大等待时间。5秒
    av_dict_set(&options, "timeout", "5000000", 0);
//设置 阻塞超时，否则可能在流断开时连接发生阻塞，微秒
    av_dict_set(&options, "stimeout", "3000000", 0);
//设置 find_stream_info 最大时长，微秒
    av_dict_set(&options, "analyzeduration", "1000000", 0);*/
    av_dict_set(&opt, "preset", "medium", 0);
    av_dict_set(&opt, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);
    av_dict_set(&opt, "profile", "baseline", 0);
    av_dump_format(outFormatCtx, 0, rtmp_url, 1);

    if (avformat_init_output(outFormatCtx, &opt) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error initializing output\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (!(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        ret = avio_open(&outFormatCtx->pb, rtmp_url, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open output file '%s'", rtmp_url);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    /*   这种方式修改没有效果，无法添加修改SDP
     * av_dict_set(&st->metadata, "title", "Cool video", 0);
       av_dict_set(&st->metadata, "Content-Base", " rtsp://10.45.12.141/h264/ch1/main/av_stream/", 0);
       av_dict_set(&st->metadata, "sprop-parameter-sets", "sdsfwedeo", 0);*/
    AVCodecParameters *codecParams = st->codecpar;
    const char *spropParameterSets = "Z0IACpZTBYmI,aMlWsA==";  // 替换为实际的sprop-parameter-sets值
    av_dict_set(&st->metadata, "sprop-parameter-sets", spropParameterSets, 0);
    avcodec_parameters_to_context(codecContext, st->codecpar);
    AVFormatContext *avFormatContext[1];
    avFormatContext[0] = outFormatCtx;
    char spd[2048];
    av_sdp_create(avFormatContext, 1, spd, sizeof(spd));
    printf("%s\n", spd);
/*    ret = avio_open(&outFormatCtx->pb, rtmp_url, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open output ,%s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        exit(1);
    }*/

/*// 设置 H264 参数
    AVDictionary *params = NULL;
    av_dict_set(&params, "profile", "main", 0);
    av_dict_set(&params, "level", "3.1", 0);

// 获取 `sprop-parameter-sets` 参数
    AVPacket *extradata = av_packet_alloc();
//    avcodec_parameters_from_context(extradata->data, codecContext);

// 获取 `sprop-parameter-sets` 参数的大小
    int sprop_parameter_sets_size = extradata->size;

// 释放资源
    av_packet_free(&extradata);

// 设置 `sprop-parameter-sets` 参数
    uint8_t *sprop_parameter_sets = extradata->data;
    codecContext->extradata = sprop_parameter_sets;
    codecContext->extradata_size = sprop_parameter_sets_size;*/

    /* Write the header */
//    ret = avformat_write_header(outFormatCtx, NULL);
    ret = avformat_write_header(outFormatCtx, &opt);
    if (ret != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred when opening output %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        exit(1);
    }

    frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }
//    frame->format = c->pix_fmt;
//    frame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    frame->format = 0;
    frame->width = codecContext->width;
    frame->height = codecContext->height;

    ret = av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate the video frame data ,%s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        exit(1);
    }

    /* encode 1 second of video */
    for (i = 0; i < 2500; i++) {
        /* ... (rest of the encoding loop) ... */
        fflush(stdout);

        /* make sure the frame data is writable */
        ret = av_frame_make_writable(frame);
        if (ret < 0)
            exit(1);

        /* prepare a dummy image */
        /* Y */
        for (y = 0; y < codecContext->height; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < codecContext->width; x++) {
                frame->data[0][y * frame->linesize[0] + x] = x + y + i * 3;
            }
        }

        /* Cb and Cr */
        for (y = 0; y < codecContext->height / 2; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < codecContext->width / 2; x++) {
                frame->data[1][y * frame->linesize[1] + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
                frame->data[2][y * frame->linesize[2] + x] = 64 + x + i * 5;
            }
        }

        frame->pts = i;

        /* encode the image */
        encode(codecContext, frame, pkt, outFormatCtx);
    }

    /* flush the encoder */
    encode(codecContext, NULL, pkt, outFormatCtx);

    /* Write the trailer */
    av_write_trailer(outFormatCtx);

    /* Close the output */
    avformat_free_context(outFormatCtx);

    avcodec_free_context(&codecContext);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    av_packet_free(&pkt);

    return 0;
}
```

I searched online for how to add "prop parameter sets", but I used their method but none of them worked. I also used WireShark to capture packets, but during the communication process, there was still no "prop parameter sets". Here is the method I tried:

```
  AVDictionary *opt = NULL;
 av_dict_set(&opt, "sprop-parameter-sets", "asdgasdfs", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the reason, but I don't know why. I just need to change the encoder from h264 to h265. I caught a packet and found that I already have the prop parameter sets parameter. Later on, I tried MPEG4 again, and it works as well.

```
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H265);
```